# why was "bandwidth" chosen to describe a rate?

Tags: download, bandwidth

It just doesn't seem to make sense to use the term "width" to describe a rate, but maybe that isn't even right.  The common thing you hear now is that you may be limited to a total amount of data downloaded which isn't a rate at all, volume is a better way to describe what is being called bandwidth.

Comment: This question does not meet the requirements outlined in the [FAQs](http://superuser.com/faq#dontask). Here is a quote that directly talks about this type of question in the FAQs: "You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face. Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page."

Comment: Pop over to the Wikipedia article on bandwidth as it explains things well.

Comment: Not particularly true that this question is "off topic" -- it's okay to ask about terminology, but the question should have rather been closed as "not constructive".

Answer (score 1):

It comes from [signal processing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bandwidth_%28signal_processing%29), where the width of the frequency band used determines how much information can be sent per unit of time.